# Converting tableData to Array suitable for Insert Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I have a virtual table that I am adding information to, that I can then export into a CSV file.
Since setting this up, I have decided that it would be useful to then store this data in the DB so that I can refer back at a later date

the table is designed to create a CSV that I can upload to my bank and pay all of my suppliers

the "virtual" table looks like

| Company | AccountName | Sortcode | AccountNumber | Reference | Payment | PaymentDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Company A | 10-10-10 | 12345678 | Ref1 | 100 | 01/05/2023 |
| Company B | Company B | 20-20-20 | 23456789 | Ref2 | 100 | 01/05/2023 |
| Company C | Company C | 30-30-30 | 34567891 | Ref3 | 100 | 01/05/2023 |

I have been using

```
parseData: () => {
        var dataset = Table1.tableData;
    var res = [];
    dataset.forEach(item => {
       res.push(Object.values(item));
    });
    return(res)
}
```

Which returns

```
[
  [
    "Company A",
    "Company A",
    "10-10-10.",
    "12345678",
    "Ref1",
    "100",
    "01/05/2023"
  ],
  [
    "Company B",
    "Company B",
    "20-20-20.",
    "23456788",
    "Ref2",
    "100",
    "01/05/2023"
  ],
  [
    "Company C",
    "Company C",
    "30-30-30.",
    "34567891",
    "Ref3",
    "100",
    "01/05/2023"
  ]
]
```

Which looks like what I want.

However, when I run the main script

```
bulkInsert: () => {
    let data = this.parseData().map(item => ({
        Company: item['Driver'],
        AccountName: item['AccountName'],
        AccountNumber: item['AccountNumber'],
        SortCode: item['Sortcode'],
        Reference: item['Reference'],
        Amount: item['Payment'],
        paymentDate: item['PaymentDate'],
    }));
    bulk_insert.run(() => {
        showAlert('Successfully added new entries');
    }, () => {}, {'data': data});
    return(data)
}
```

`return(data) gives

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

Ideally I would like the output to match what is output from the 1st function
That would then allow `bulk_insert.run` to insert the rows from the table to the database